# unable to add value to html textbox of type password

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

hi all am trying to load values from cookies to the text box.My HTMLis as below

```
<fieldset class="boxBody">
    <label id="dis" style="margin:0 auto;display:none"></label>
    <label>Username</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Username" id="txtUsername" runat="server" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username"  />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="txtpassword" runat="server" placeholder="Password"  tabindex="2" />
</fieldset>
```

and my code in pageload is

```
txtUsername.Value = Request.Cookies["SN"]["UserName"];
txtpassword.Value = Request.Cookies["SN"]["Password"];
```

what happens is instead of password only the placeholder is visible.when i change the type to text it works.Any way to add text when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the attribute, as a workaround:

```
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", Request.Cookies["SN"]["Password"])
```

Disclaimer: Pre-filling passwords may not be a good idea.

Comment: does not work .Tried it already.Is it because of the placeholder

Comment: No. Placeholder is not an issue. Its an html input, which is why. Change it to `asp:textbox` server control with `textmode="password"`. But beware, the password can be seen in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to hide the password cause if its not you can change the text of txtPassword to asterisks

> textmode="Password"

Comment: in html input type ="password", in asp textmode="password"